# Many to Many search queries with JPQL

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, java-ee-6, jpql

An employe is assigned to one or many services.

A service can be assigned to 0 or many employes.

I want to select the services that are assigned for an employe e.

Here is my Employe entity:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Employe.findAll", query="SELECT e FROM Employe e")
public class Employe implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int idemp;

    //bi-directional *..* association avec service
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name="employerservice"
        , joinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="IDEMP")
            }
        , inverseJoinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="IDSERVICE")
            }
        )
    private List<Service> services;


    public Employe() {
        services = new ArrayList<Service>();
    }

    public int getIdemp() {
        return this.idemp;
    }

    public void setIdemp(int idemp) {
        this.idemp = idemp;
    }

    public List<Service> getServices() {
        return this.services;
    }

    public void setServices(List<Service> services) {
        this.services = services;
    }
}
```

Here is my Service entity:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Service.findAll", query="SELECT s FROM Service s")
public class Service implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int idservice;

    private String nomservice;

    //bi-directional *..* association avec Employe
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="services")
    private List<Employe> employes;

    public Service() {
    }

    public int getIdservice() {
        return this.idservice;
    }

    public void setIdservice(int idservice) {
        this.idservice = idservice;
    }

    public String getNomservice() {
        return this.nomservice;
    }

    public void setNomservice(String nomservice) {
        this.nomservice = nomservice;
    }

    public List<Employe> getEmployes() {
        return this.employes;
    }
    public void setEmployes(List<Employe> employes) {
        this.employes = employes;
    }

}
```

After having some trouble trying to fetch everything using Fetch = Fetch.EAGER; I decided to do everything manually and adding more functions to in the ejb sessions methods.

I tried this:

```
public List<Service> selectServicesByEmploye(int idemp){
    List<Service> res = new ArrayList<Service>();
        Query req = em.createQuery("select s from service s join s.employes" 
                + " e where e.idemp LIKE :idemp "+
                "").setParameter("idemp", idemp);
        res = req.getResultList();
    return res;
    }
```

Any ideas on how to write an hql query that can do this ?

Comment: Well, the query is in your question. Except using `like` on a number doesn't make sense. Use '='. And that your entity is named `Service`, not `service`. This query should have caused an exception to be thrown, and you should have read, and posted, the exception stack trace.

Comment: thanks a lot! I don't know how i didn't notice this